# How to hide a drive in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, drive

Ubuntu 18.04, Gnome. I'd like to hide my drive that's dedicated to windows, in my Nautilus file explorer, under other locations.

I already used "disks" app to edit mount options of that disk and unchecked "show in user interface" and "mount at system startup". Rebooted. Same issue.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but I want to hide the entire DRIVE and not just a partition on that drive.

Comment: What Windows calls **C: drive** is a partition. in Nautilus if "an entire drive" has two partitions they appear separately. You will have to hide the two separately.

Comment: Gotcha. Well I know on solus it was as simple as going into disks app as I mentioned above, and disabling it from appearing. Would you suggest I follow the advice in the other commentors link?

Comment: Please follow the link and read all the answers first. If I were you, I would try the GUI based answer first before trying to edit any system files like `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: I see what I did. I did the gui method through disks app, but I only hid it's boot partition and not the main file system/the other partition. Now that I've done that, it's not showing in Nautilus. Success!